# Vuex state updates break v-for reactivity

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, state, vuex, store

I am trying to make a Notification component in Nuxt using the built-in Vuex store. I have two components, `Notifications.vue` and `Notification.vue` to display the notifications. My store has two mutations, one for adding a notification and another for removing one.

Here are the relevant files from my project:

**store/notifications.js**

```js
export const state = () => ({
    notifications: []
});

export const getters = {
    allNotifications: state => state.notifications
};

export const mutations = {
    PUSH_NOTIFICATION(state, notification) {
        state.notifications.push(notification);
    },
    REMOVE_NOTIFICATION(state, notificationToRemove) {
    // PROBLEM ---> Updates state but breaks reactivity
        state.notifications = [
            ...state.notifications.filter(notification => notification.id != notificationToRemove)
        ];
};

export const actions = {
    async pushNotification({ commit }, notification) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            notification = {
                ...notification,
                id: (Math.random().toString(36) + Date.now().toString(36)).substr(2)
            };
            commit('PUSH_NOTIFICATION', notification);
            resolve(notification.id);
        });
    },
    async removeNotification({ commit }, id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            commit('REMOVE_NOTIFICATION', id);
            resolve();
        });
    }
};
```

**plugins/notifications.js**

```js
export default ({ store }, inject) => {
    let notifications = {
        async notify(notification) {
            return await store.dispatch('notifications/pushNotification', notification);
        },
        async removeNotification(id) {
            console.log(`The notification with the id ${id} will be removed!`);
            await store.dispatch('notifications/removeNotification', id);
            return true;
        }
    };
    // This allows me to access the methods above from any component like `this.$notifications`
    inject('notifications', notifications);

};
```

**components/Notifications.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="notifications">
        <button @click="test()">Notify</button><!-- This is to test adding new notifications -->
        <div class="notification-bounds">
            <Notification v-for="notification in notifications" :key="notification.id" :id="notification.id">{{ notification.content }}</Notification>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                notifications: this.$store.getters['notifications/allNotifications']
            };
        },
        methods: {
            test() {
                // This works therefore `PUSH_NOTIFICATION` does not break reactivity
                this.$notifications.notify({ content: 'Test' }); 
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

**components/Notification.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="notification">
        <slot></slot>
        <button @click="close()">Close</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'id'
        ],
        methods: {
            close(){
    // PROBLEM ---> This updates the state internally but it breaks reactivity so 
    // there is something wrong with the `REMOVE_NOTIFICATION` mutation.
                this.$notifications.removeNotification(this.id) 

            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

The problem is that the `REMOVE_NOTIFICATION` mutation breaks the reactivity of the `v-for` in `Notifications.vue`. How should I solve this?

Comment: It's kinda complex to figure out what is the issue with all of this logic and not visual indication of "breaks the reactivity". Meanwhile, since you're using Vue2 behind Nuxt, you are maybe within the array caveats? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Comment: @kissu I don't think I am within the array caveats since I'm not setting a specific property of the `notifications` array nor changing its length like `state.notifications.length = newLength`. I am simply setting the `notifications` array to a new array returned by the `filter` method. I think it's as if I were doing this in `REMOVE_NOTIFICATION`: `state.notifications = newNotificationsArray`.

Comment: @kissu By the way, when I say "breaks the reactivity" I mean that the state is correctly mutated by `REMOVE_NOTIFICATION` (I can verify this by calling `window.$nuxt.$store.getters['notifications/allNotifications'];` in the browser console which returns the update state correctly.) but the changes are not reflected in the browser page so when I remove a notification the browser doesn't remove the corresponding `Notification` component from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the lack of *reactivity* is because you do fetch your notifications inside of `data`.
`data` is aimed to be static and not recompute any changes, indeed.

Try this one in your `Notifications.vue` file

```html
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    notifications() {
      return this.$store.getters['notifications/allNotifications']
    },
  },
}
</script>
```